# variable length flutter

Tags: flutter

alguien me puede ayudar, nose porque no reconoce la variable .length
He probado en ponerle !length pero nada.
GRACIAS*texto en itálica*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar el código como texto no como imagen ya que puede no ser visible para todos los miembros de la comunidad, edita tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: pon el cursor sobre el error y dinos que aparece, además intenta con data!.length

Comment: Prueba a poner el tipo de lo que devuelve el fetchWpPosts() en la clase FutureBuilder. Supongamos que devuelve una lista de Perros (por poner algo),  quedaría FutureBuilder<List<Perro>>

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente puede ser porque snapshot.data por defecto es una variable del tipo dynamic y para encontrar la propiedad ".length" la variable debe ser del tipo List.

Prueba de definir el tipo de información que trata el Future de la siguiente forma:

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>?>(
   future: futureName,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if(snapshot.hasData){
       return Widget();
     }
     else return Widget();
   }
```